# Energy Spectrum of lattice Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, simulations

[Here](https://topocondmat.org/w1_topointro/1D.html) the author has done numerical calculation and has plotted  energy spectrum and wave function for Kiteav Chain whose hamiltonian is given by
$$H=-\mu\sum_n c_n^\dagger c_n-t\sum_n (c_{n+1}^\dagger c_n+\textrm{h.c.}) + \Delta\sum_n (c_n c_{n+1}+\textrm{h.c.})$$
I was wondering how can we also do the same using mathematica or any other tools.

**Question**
So, for given hamiltonian how can we calculate the energy spectrum and wave function numerically?

Note: The author has used $n=35$ as lattice size.

Comment: If we write $ d_m := \sum_n U_{m,n} c_n $, what kind of matrix can $U$ be if we want to preserve the fermionic commutation relations? How does this transform the Hamiltonian? How would the Hamiltonian look if we want it to be diagonal in these new $d_m$ variables? By going through this logic carefully, you will see how you can diagonalize the Hamiltonian numerically for thousands of sites in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @RubenVerresen Do you mean diagonalising by doing Fourier transform followed by Bogolibouv transformation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose a basis.
2. Write the Hamiltonian matrix in that basis (e.g. like it's done [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560288).)
3. Diagonalise the Hamiltonian. That will give you the eigenenergies and energy wavefunctions.
   On Mathematica, for instance, you'd use `Eigensystem`.

Comment: In principle matrix for $\hat a$ or $\hat a^\dagger$ is infinite-dimensional. But since I say: I like to work with 35 sites on lattice! Then my matrix dimension of $\hat a$ or $\hat a^\dagger$ is 35x35?

Comment: Well, you'd need a different $a$ and $a^\dagger$ for *each* site

Comment: Since we are dealing with fermions $\hat a$ will be 2x2 matrix?

Comment: I think so. Provided you find a matrix representation such that $a^\dagger$$^2 = 0$.

Comment: For fermions it might be more complicated though: look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62604/matrix-representation-for-fermionic-annihilation-operator